# Make A Variable Lower Case in A PHP Function

Tags: php

I have a php function:

`function returnFirst($rsrnum)  {
      $char = substr($rsrnum, 0, 1);
         return ctype_alpha($char) ? $char : "#";
}`

It grabs the first letter of a string (i.e. "ZT-FUL-ULT-10SF-S" would return "Z") and if the first character is a number, it returns a "#" symbol.

But all the strings are upper case when they get returned, but I need them to be lower case.  So in the previous example "ZT-FUL-ULT-10SF-S" would return "Z", I need it to return "z".  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: [String functions](http://php.net/strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just convert the result using [`strtolower()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
function returnFirst($rsrnum) {
    $char = substr($rsrnum, 0, 1);
    return ctype_alpha($char) ? strtolower($char) : "#";
}
```

Or, you can do the following:

```
$result = strtolower( returnFirst($string) );
```